# Is the condition defining a Ramanujan graph equivalent to the Ramanujan conjecture ?

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

I just learnt that a  $ d $-regular graph  $ G $  is a Ramanujan graph if  $\lambda(G)\leq 2\sqrt{d-1} $, and that this condition is equivalent to the Ihara zeta function fulfilling the analog of RH.

But the condition defining a Ramanujan graph is formally analogous to the Ramanujan conjecture  $ \tau(p)\leq 2\sqrt{p^{k-1}} $ with  $ k=12 $ the weight of the cusp form whose Fourier coefficients are the  $\tau(n) $ in a  " $ \log p $ free" form.

So can an L-function fulfilling both the Ramanujan conjecture and RH be viewed as the Ihara zeta function of some  $ d $ -regular graph with  $ d $ depending in a way to be precised on the considered L-function ? As the definition of a Ramanujan graph is independent of any prime number, is it actually some kind of archimedean Ramanujan conjecture ?

Comment: RH stand for Riemann (sp) Hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, as it's customary.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but [I think] the original Ramanujan graph constructions used the fact that the Ramanujan conjecture was proved true for certain instances. Meanwhile, there are constructions for $d$-regular Ramanujan graphs for **all** positive integers $d \ge 3$ (the running time is something like $dn^2$ I believe where $n$ is the number of vertices in your desired graph), where the bound on the 2nd-largest eigenvalue is established by more elementary analysis i.e., no deep number theory. Interlacing polynomials I believe

Comment: Google "Ramanujan Graphs In Polynomial Time" by Michael B Cohen